# How to use iam role when creating aws eks cluster with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create aws eks cluster with terraform. I want to use an existing iam role. I won't be creating a new role. I tried this.

```
module 'eks' {
...
iam_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/cluster-role"
...
}
```

But I get 403 permission denied. How can I this? Thanks.

Edit: added error.
 `failed creating IAM Role (green-eks-node-group): AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::*******:user/****** is not authorized to perform: iam:TagRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::*******:role/green-eks-node`

Comment: Does your user have a permission to access the role that you trying to use? The reason can be that.

Comment: Get a 403 while doing what? Running `terraform apply`?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun I have permission.

Comment: @jordanm yes. running time

Comment: Can you post the actual error message including the operation it got permission denied on?

Comment: I added to question

Answer (score 0):

First for good measure: Please do not post pictures here of either code or error messages. Just copy paste the stuff and format it.

That said: I think the error tells you exactly what is wrong (or at least what the first error is, because in my experience it takes a few iterations of this to get your IAM permissions straight).

The role that you use you execute terraform does not have the permission:

```
iam:TagRole
```

on the resource:

```
arn:aws:iam:xxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks-cluster
```

So you will need to add it to it's policy.

Comment: Thanks for informing about this. I edited it again. I understand what you wrote, I will try it now. Thanks.